# How to pass results from db query to Vue?

Tags: javascript, mysql, http, express, vue.js

I have an API request that calls a SQL query within the function. I am trying to pass the results to a .vue page. (Using express-vue) Here is the api request

```
router.get('/search', (req, res, next) => {

    var keyword = ("%" + req.query.keyword + "%")
    var lat = req.query.lat
    var lng = req.query.lng

    console.log(keyword, lat, lng)

    connection.query('SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos (cos ( radians(?) )* cos( radians( lat ) )* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) )+ sin ( radians(?) )* sin( radians( lat ) ))) AS distance FROM job_posting where job_title like ? HAVING distance < 25', [
        lat, lng, lat, keyword
    ], function(err, rows) {

     })
  res.render('main', {
  // data: {
  //           results
  //         },
    vue: {
        meta: {
            title: 'Page Title',
        },
        components: ['myheader', 'myfooter', 'searchform', , 'results']
    }

});
})
```

and the Main.vue page

```
<template>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div id="main-container" class="container col-md-10">

        <myheader></myheader>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <searchform></searchform>
        <results></results>


        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>


    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Im trying to pass the data to this component results.vue

```
<template>

<p>Display data</p>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            // dogs: 3
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

How do I pass the "rows" data to the results.vue page?

here is how the data is coming from the DB

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    job_title: 'Software Engineer',
    job_desc: '<p>Ayo</p>',
    location: 'Akron, OH',
    job_type: 'Full-Time',
    salary: '',
    date_created: 2016-11-23T05:00:00.000Z,
    short_desc: 'yyoyo@gmail.com',
    apply_url: 'Ayo',
    lat: '41.084821',
    lng: '-81.515607',
    distance: 0 },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    job_title: 'Software Engineer',
    job_desc: '<p>Ayo</p>',
    location: 'Akron, OH',
    job_type: 'Full-Time',
    salary: '',
    date_created: 2016-11-23T05:00:00.000Z,
    short_desc: 'yyoyo@gmail.com',
    apply_url: 'Ayo',
    lat: '41.084821',
    lng: '-81.515607',
    distance: 0 },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 3,
    job_title: 'Software Engineer',
    job_desc: '<p>Ayo</p>',
    location: 'Akron, OH',
    job_type: 'Full-Time',
    salary: '',
    date_created: 2016-11-23T05:00:00.000Z,
    short_desc: 'yyoyo@gmail.com',
    apply_url: 'Ayo',
    lat: '41.084821',
    lng: '-81.515607',
    distance: 0 } ]
```

Comment: Looks like you have a Main.vue that has a Results.vue component. You typically pass data from parent components to child components using props. So it should be something like  <results :results="results"></results>, where results is a data property on Main.vue (which it looks like you commented out). You also need to move the render inside the callback as @johnnynotsolucky did in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about express-vue, however I don't think making API calls from a route definition is a good idea.

Rather pass the `lat` and `lng` parameters through to your `results` component, and make the API call there, using a method, or the [created()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) hook for example. It could make it a bit easier to change the implementation of the API in the future:

```
res.render('main', {
  data: {
    lat,
    lng,
  },
  vue: {
    meta: {
    title: 'Page Title',
  },
  components: ['myheader', 'myfooter', 'searchform', , '
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really need to query data from the route, and assuming the `rows` is an array of javascript objects, you can render your component within the callback of the query:

```
connection.query('SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos (cos ( radians(?) )* cos( radians( lat ) )* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) )+ sin ( radians(?) )* sin( radians( lat ) ))) AS distance FROM job_posting where job_title like ? HAVING distance < 25', [
    lat, lng, lat, keyword
], function(err, rows) {
  res.render('main', {
    data: {
      results: rows
    },
    vue: {
      meta: {
        title: 'Page Title',
    },
    components: ['myheader', 'myfooter', 'searchform', 'results']
  }
  next(); // You probably need to call this
})
```

Don't forget to call `next()`.

Comment: I need to pass the objects from the DB results as the data to the component. Sorry I should of explained that part better. So basically I need to pass the "rows" result from the sql query.

Comment: Updated. What I meant originally was that you could execute that query from within the component, or from some other external module rather than have it inside the route itself where that logic could distort the intention of the route, and possibly make it harder to read.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll test that solution out and report back. Thanks!